# activeIndex in $e.mobile.history doesn't behave like expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I make a jquery mobile app which switches between two pages. In pagebeforeshow event I fill some dom elements with data from a JSON object. When a user hits a back button then I get the id of the data of the specific page from the history stack (I put it there in the first onPageBeforeShow event).

```
onPageBeforeShow: function() {

        // if fact id already exists in history stack take it from there (only happens when "back" is pressed)
        var urlh = $.mobile.urlHistory;
        if( "factId" in urlh.stack[urlh.activeIndex] ) {

            // load 
            cp10.score.currentFactId = urlh.stack[urlh.activeIndex].factId;

        } else {

            // store fact id in history object
            urlh.stack[urlh.activeIndex].factId = cp10.score.currentFactId;
        } 

        ... go on and fill dom elements with current id
```

That works fine for the back button. When I hit forward again there is a funny behaviour of the $e.mobile.history.activeIndex element. For example I go forward in the app three pages, so activeIndex is 3. Then with the browser back button I go ...

... back: activeIndex is 2
back: activeIndex is 1
back: activeIndex is 0
forward: activeIndex is 1
forward: activeIndex is 0

That supposed to be 2, i think. I'm puzzled.

What could be the reason that a browser forward button press results in a decrease of activeIndex?